# Fluorinefx Error Emailing

Tags: c#, log4net, fluorinefx

Has anyone ever set up error emailing with Fluorinefx?

Update: Found the answer with the SmtpAppender in log4net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluorinefx uses log4net as its logging source.  You can add this appender (and the error level warning) and all is well.  Note, the documentation (ala xml) says that smtp authentication won't work unless you are in a 1.1 runtime.  Sounds crazy, and it is.  At least in log4net 2.0.5+, authentication works, but the code still says it won't.

`<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <to value="to@someware.com" />
      <from value="from@someware.com" />
      <subject type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{log4net:HostName} Error: %appdomain" />
      <smtpHost value="smtp.sendgrid.net" />
      <username value="blah"/>
      <password value="dee"/>
      <authentication value="Basic"/>
      <bufferSize value="512" />
      <lossy value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>`